# CSS webkit keyframe not working in safari

Tags: css, webkit

I have the following CSS animation:

```
.fade-in {
    opacity: 0; /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1; /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.fade-in.one {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.fade-in.two {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.2s;
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.fade-in.three {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.7s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.7s;
    animation-delay: 1.7s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Any reason why it's not working on Safari?

I have tested and neither safari desktop neither mobile is working.

I have also opened it in my ios with chrome, but it did not worked as well.

It's working only on desktop chrome and desktop mozilla.

Check the link:

https://festive-shockley-460d95.netlify.com

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem because only some animation types work in safari. Please refer to this link if you want to learn more information about this. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation
Therefore, your safari version may not be the latest version which is leading to the animations not working. your welcome...